# How to find an homeomorphism between $S^1$ and the image of a Cardioid

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, curves

I have to show an homeomorphism between the circle $S^1$ and the image of the Cardioid using this parametrization
$$\gamma : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\\ t \mapsto ((1-\cos(t))\sin(t) , (1-\cos(t))\cos(t))
$$
So I have to find an bijective application and prove that is an homeomorphism.

Comment: Do you know the concepts of topological quotient (like $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$) and quotient maps?

Comment: Do you mean the second coordinate to be $((1-\cos (t))) \cos (t)$ ? Otherwise it looks like it could be $1=\cos^2(t)$ which is just $\sin^2(t).$

Comment: sorry i made a mistake with brackets. @coffeemath

Comment: @Didier yes I know the topological quotient.

Comment: @AlessandroRecchia Great. Then notice that your map $\gamma$ is $2\pi$ periodic and hence induces a continuous map on the quotient $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Now, use the homeomorphism $S^1 \simeq \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and conclude that the induced map is an homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: Oh now it's clear. Thank you so much! @Didier